# What is the difference between IDbSet and DbSet?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

What is the difference between

```
public IDbSet<Chrip> Chirps { get; set; }
```

and

```
public DbSet<Chrip> Chirps { get; set; }
```

Are they the same?

Comment: One exposes an interface the other a class, and no they are not the same.

Comment: No, they are not the same.  A question like this needs more context - do you understand inheritance?  The difference between a class and an interface?  Provide more information on your question to get a better answer.

Answer (score 21):

[Sam I am's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443037/what-is-the-difference-between-idbset-and-dbset/38443098#38443098) neatly defines the difference between an interface and a class, but there are additional considerations when choosing which to use in your code.

Specifically - a class can implement more than one interface, or can implement methods and properties not defined by *any* interface.

In this case, the [`IDbSet<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg679233.aspx) interface defines *most* of the methods and properties used by the [`DbSet<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg696460.aspx) class, but not all of them.  For example, the `FindAsync`, `RemoveRange` and `SqlQuery` methods only exist on the concrete class implementation.  If you use the interface in your code, you won't have those particular methods available without first casting to the concrete type.

Also, [the Remarks section in the MSDN for `IDbSet<TEntity>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg679233.aspx#Anchor_4) has another interesting point:

> `IDbSet<TEntity>` was originally intended to allow creation of test doubles (mocks or fakes) for `DbSet<TEntity>`. However, this approach has issues in that adding new members to an interface breaks existing code that already implements the interface without the new members. Therefore, starting with EF6, no new members will be added to this interface and it is recommended that `DbSet<TEntity>` be used as the base class for test doubles.

I believe it it safe to extend that line of thinking to say that you should usually declare your properties using `DbSet<TEntity>` instead of `IDbSet<TEntity>` unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: As of today (Nov 2021) why would someone create an IDbSet - can you give an example - this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when a type name begins with an `I` it is an interface.  This is not a hard rule, but just a naming convention.

`DbSet` probably implements `IDbSet`

---

Suppose you have an interface like this

```
public interface IFoo
{
    int Echo(int bar);
}
```

A class would implement an interface like this

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Echo(int bar)
    {
        return bar;
    }
}
```

What this means is that your class `Foo` must implement every method the interface says it does, which in this case is a method named `Echo` which takes an `int` as input, and returns an `int`.

What this allows you to do is to is to treat a bunch of different classes the same way, even if you don't know how they're implemented.  For more information, see [Polymorphism](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

They refer to different namespaces. One is for EF Core and the other is not recommended.

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<T>
System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<T>
```